# setting title to last tab bar item in uitabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm currently using `uitabbarcontroller`. My app has 6 tab items. While trying to set the title of my last tab item using the below code returns an error.

Code:

```
   [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:5] setTitle:@"title"];
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

but actually there is 6 tab items in my app. Finally i have achieved the result using

```
  [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"title"];
```

Please help me out to find why the above error occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `tabBarController` customized? Does it always show 6 items? What prints `[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items count]`? How did you set the others items? iPhone? iPad? Since in iPhone, normally the max numbers items are 5 (which make your error message sensed).

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I have found what is wrong with my code. Actually i trying to set title for view controllers which is under more items tab using the above code.Because of that it has thrown an error. Thanks for helping me to resolve my problem.